# Booking solution for small car rental

Tags: web-apps, booking

I'm looking for a solution for booking rental cars. My current booking site is running with an old Typ03 extension that is no longer supported. Car rentals are a tiny amount compared to the rest of the business, so I would love to have something relatively cheap. I was thinking of using something similar to Microsoft Bookings or a simple Website with a Wordpress Plugin for the booking part.

All in all, I need something that has:

- a calendar that is visible right away and displays if the car is available.
- a booking system that allows the customer to decide how many days to rent the car and me being able to set a min amount of days (this was the main issue with Microsoft Bookings)
- a system that after the customer orders the car sends out an e-mail with their contact information